# Letsencrypt certificate for www and non-www domain

Tags: ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I have generated SSL certificate like so:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone
```

Then I was asked for email ... and a domain name. I entered `example.com`

I figured out that I could enter multiple domains to be included in one certificate using different approach. E.g.:

```
sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

I wonder if I could have entered multiple domains when I was promoted for them in a dialog or now I need to regenerate using a different approach?

Do I need to remove previous letsencrypt installation before going new way?

**UPDATE -> SOLVED**

```
sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

Comment: You can add host names to existing certificates and renew the signing. Have a look here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/adding-a-new-domain-name-to-existing-cert/10992

Answer (score 94):

You do not need to remove the installed certificate.

You can extend it to your sub-domain if you're using the same domain. Do the following:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

When prompted for Expanding or Cancelling, reply with E then hit Enter key on your keyboard.

The certificate should be setup successfully.

If you encounter this error: **Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6,** stop Apache by running `systemctl stop apache2` then run the above certbot command again.

Once the SSL certificate is successfuly setup, run `systemctl restart apache2` to get Apache up and running again.

Comment: I have setted cronjob to auto renew - does the auto renew will renew both of them? (and all other certificates as well?)

Comment: Yes it will renew both of them @raz

Comment: I got `Failed authorization procedure` for www, `DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www...`

Comment: @JosephK. ensure your A records are correct from your DNS configurations.

Comment: I had to stop apache in order for certbot to be able to expand cert. Other than that this solution worked great !

Comment: @AdamW the process of stopping apache is covered in the above answer as well, maybe you missed it.

Comment: It should be noted that you should not use `certonly` here if you intend for certbot to manage the www domain as well as the bare domain in your webserver's config. If you're using nginx, for instance, you would put `--nginx` in place of `certonly`.

Comment: Thank you!!! Initially i installed SSL with ```sudo certbot certonly --nginx``` for my server block for ```example.com```, and then added the ```www.example.com``` to my server block and followed your instructions by running ```sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com```, i could successfully extend the certificate.

Comment: Confirmed working in 14 Feb 2024. Happy valentine's!