# redirect https non-www to https www for nginx django

Tags: python, django, nginx, linode

I tried many solutions but nothing worked. I am trying to redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com. If I write https://example.com in the address bar, I get an insecure website prompt. I have ssl certificate installed for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
Here's the code from nginx server:

```
server {
    server_name exmaple.com www.exmaple.com;

    location ~ ^/.well-known {
        root /home/xyz/xyz-dir;
        allow all;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/xyz/xyz-dir;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/xyz/xyz-dir;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.exmaple.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.exmaple.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.exmaple.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = exmaple.com) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name exmaple.com www.exmaple.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `location ~` instead of `location /`

as you commented it's not work:
updated

use bellow links:

https://nginx.viraptor.info/

https://nginxconfig.org/

as you can see [here](https://nginxconfig.org/?domains.0.php.php=false&domains.0.python.python=true&domains.0.python.djangoRules=true&domains.0.routing.root=false)

although browsers redirect http to https, you should add:

```
# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name .example.com;
    include     nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

maybe your problem will solved by this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54859776/5987259

Comment: Tried this solution but facing the same problem. https://example.com not redirecting to https://www.example.com

Comment: I even tried:  if ($scheme://$host = https://example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    } . But that didn't work too

Comment: Tried many solutions. Spent my whole day finding the solution to this problem but still I couldn't make it. I'm new to Nginx so I don't know how to work with those two links provided above.

Comment: Getting an error on running sudo nginx -t. Error is:
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/xyz:65
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed.

Comment: comment it and try again @Nii

Comment: Thanks for commenting  @Hamid Shariati. I tried solutions from here: https://gist.github.com/leeoniya/ff19bc6e6237f80e33b6985476f8c791 . But still getting en error while redirecting from example.com to www.example.com over https.

Comment: updated again @Niiteesh